# Logic error in how to narrow down numbers for guess a number program

Tags: java, loops, numbers

I am currently working on a "guess a number" project. The prompt asks the user to think of a number between 1 and 1000 (including 1 and 1000).My problem is the logic behind the "higher" and "lower" conditionals.

I have tried so many combinations yet my code still does not match the input code. I sort of understand why but I cant put it together on why it doesn't narrow down my numbers.

```
String text;
int min = 1;
int max = 1000;
int guess = 500;
int guess1, guess2;

while (!text.equals("yes")){
  System.out.println("Is your number " + (guess) + "?");
  System.out.println("yes,higher,or lower");
  text = reader.nextLine();
  if (text.equals("higher")){
    min = guess;
    guess1 = ((max - min+1)/2);
    guess = guess1 + min;
  }
  if (text.equals("lower")){
    min = guess;
    guess = (max - min)/2;
  }
}
}
}
```

I am currently trying to guess 300. This is MY OUTPUT:
   `Is your number 500?
    yes,higher,or lower
    lower
    Is your number 250?
    yes,higher,or lower
    higher
     Is your number 625?
     yes,higher,or lower
     lower
     Is your number 187?
    yes,higher,or lower
     higher
     Is your number 594?
     yes,higher,or lower
     lower
      Is your number 203?
     yes,higher,or lower`
HERE IS THE DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Is your number 500?
yes, higher, or lower
 lower
 Is your number 250?
 yes, higher, or lower
 higher
Is your number 375?
yes, higher, or lower
 lower
 Is your number 312?
 yes, higher, or lower
 lower
 Is your number 281?
 yes, higher, or lower
 higher
 Is your number 296?
 yes, higher, or lower
 higher
  Is your number 304?
  yes, higher, or lower
  lower
 Is your number 300?
 yes, higher, or lower
  yes
```

Comment: I'd recommend either playing computer with pencil and paper, or just using a debugger--figure out what's actually happening and figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never updating max variable, but you are using it to compute guess value.
I would recommend, going sth like this.

```
while (!text.equals("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Is your number " + (guess) + "?");
        System.out.println("yes,higher,or lower");
        text = reader.nextLine();

        if (text.equals("higher")) {
            min = guess;
        }
        if (text.equals("lower")) {
            max = guess;
        }
        guess = (max + min) / 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting `min` and `max` correctly.

In the `lower` case, you want to set `max` to `guess - 1`, since you've eliminated `guess`.  Also, set the new `guess` to the average of `max` and `min` by adding them, not subtracting them.

In the `upper` case, you don't need the variable `guess1`.  Just set `min` to `guess + 1`, since you've eliminated `guess`, and again set `guess` to the average of `max` and `min`.

```
if (text.equals("higher")){
    min = guess + 1;
    guess = (max + min)/2;
}
if (text.equals("lower")){
    max = guess - 1;
    guess = (max + min)/2;
}
```